# How to open the second form?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, forms

I have Form1 and Form2 in my project. Form2 is just a form with settings for Form1. What is the command to open the Form2 from the Form1 and also what's the command to close it please?

Answer (score 57, accepted):

You need to handle an *event* on Form1 that is raised as a result of user interaction. For example, if you have a "Settings" button that the user clicks in order to show the settings form (Form2), you should handle the `Click` event for that button:

```
private void settingsButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Create a new instance of the Form2 class
    Form2 settingsForm = new Form2();

    // Show the settings form
    settingsForm.Show();
}
```

In addition to the [`Show` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.show.aspx), you could also choose to use the [`ShowDialog` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.showdialog.aspx). The difference is that the latter shows the form as a *modal dialog*, meaning that the user cannot interact with the other forms in your application until they close the modal form. This is the same way that a message box works. The `ShowDialog` method also returns a value indicating how the form was closed.

---

When the user closes the settings form (by clicking the "X" in the title bar, for example), Windows will automatically take care of closing it.

If you want to close it yourself before the user asks to close it, you can call the form's [`Close` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx):

```
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 8):

If you want to open `Form2` modally (meaning you can't click on Form1 while Form2 is open), you can do this:

```
using (Form2 f2 = new Form2()) 
{
    f2.ShowDialog(this);
}
```

If you want to open Form2 non-modally (meaning you can still click on Form1 while Form2 is open), you can create a form-level reference to Form2 like this:

```
private Form2 _f2;

public void openForm2()
{
    _f2 = new Form2();
    _f2.Show(this); // the "this" is important, as this will keep Form2 open above 
                    // Form1.
}

public void closeForm2()
{
    _f2.Close();
    _f2.Dispose();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

```
//To open the form

Form2 form2 = new Form2();

form2.Show();
// And to close
form2.Close();
```

Hope this helps

Comment: OK thank you, it works nice...and if I set something in form2 like int a ....and I want the main form1 after closing the form2 know what is in INT a?

Comment: Well since you have an instance of Form2 on your main form you could always have a property to access that int value.  Just make sure you store that int value before you close the form :)

Answer (score 5):

I assume your talking about windows forms:

To display your form use the Show() method:

```
Form form2 = new Form();
form2.Show();
```

to close the form use Close():

```
form2.Close();
```

Comment: OK thank you, it works nice...and if I set something in form2 like int a ....and I want the main form1 after closing the form2 know what is in INT a?

Answer (score 4):

In a single line it would be:

```
(new Form2()).Show();
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 3):

On any click event (or other one):

```
Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
frm2.Show();
```

Answer (score 2):

Respectively [Form.Show()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/szcefbbd.aspx) (or [Form.ShowDialog()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w61zzfwe.aspx) if you want the second form to be modal), and [Form.Hide()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.hide.aspx) (or [Form.Close()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.close.aspx), depending on what you mean by `close it`).

Answer (score 1):

If you need to show `Form2` as a [modal dialog](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modal_dialog), from within `Form1` do:

```
var form2 = new Form2();
if (form2.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
{
    // process results here
}
```

A modal dialog will retain focus while it is open; it will set the parent windows (`Form1`) "in the background" until it is closed, which is quite a common practice for settings windows.

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

```
var dlg = new Form2();
dlg.ShowDialog();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Form1 OpenNewForm = new Form1();
OpenNewForm.Show();
```

"OpenNewForm" is the name of the Form.
In the second the form opens.

If you want to close the previous form:

```
this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

In C#.Net if you're inside of a Solution, and inside of a Project, and Form2 (with Form2.cs) is inside of  ,

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
       ProjectName.Form2 secondaryForm= new ProjectName.Form2();

       secondaryForm.Show();
    }
```