# Show a new form when click a button

Tags: c#, winforms

I am new in c#. I am trying to show a new form (form2) when click button in form1.

this is my code.

```
        using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SliceEngine
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {   
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.ShowDialog();            
         }
    }
}
```

the error show

> the type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

this is my code for form2.

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace SliceEngine
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

for form2, i just making the design interface.

all i know when using java, i only need to declare the object first. what should i do for this?

Comment: Have you created a `Form2` form in your project?

Comment: Please confirm that `Form2` exists in your code. Remember, the file name doesn't always relate to the class inside it, so be sure to double check.

Comment: FYI:  You don't 'call' a form, you display or show a form.

Comment: @sarabrown, could you please post your two code examples so we can see what's happening?

Comment: @Spiritfyre: i already edit my post.

Comment: Is Form2 in the same project (not just the same solution) as Form1? Did you actually copy+paste this code, or did you type it out? You may have hidden the problem if this isn't your whole code.

Comment: Are you sure that yours forms are in the same assembly? It could happen that the namespaces are the same, but the project that contains the Form1 does not have a reference to the other project (if there are in different projects of course)

Comment: Duplicate of following?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5718183/how-to-open-the-second-form

Answer (score 6):

I don't see any reason to fail your code, unless you have any typo. I have tried the same code as yours and it worked well on my machine.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace winapp
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
            private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
                frm2.ShowDialog();
            }
        }




    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Windows.Forms;

    namespace winapp
    {
        public partial class Form2 : Form
        {
            public Form2()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

> the type or namespace name 'Form2' could not be found (are you missing
>   a using directive or an assembly reference?)

It means that you forgot to add the namespace that points to the `Form2` directory to your code

If you have got a `Form2.cs` inside a directory named `UI` and that directory is inside `MyForms` directory, then the whole tree would be **`ProjectName`** >> **`MyForms`** >> **`UI`** >> **`Form2.cs`**

So you should use this namespace in your code

```
using ProjectName.MyForms.UI;
```

Now I should be able to start showing it easily cause I've added its location.

```
new Form2().Show();
```

**OR** instead of all that and bother adding a namespace, you can just use:

```
new ProjectName.MyForms.UI.Form2().Show();
```

Answer (score 1):

In form1, you are using the constructor for Form2:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

if you change it to

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
```

you should be fine.

Comment: owh im sorry. i slightly typing error in this post. My real code is just like yours. could u help me for this, please @competent_tech

Answer (score 1):

Your code *claims* you don't have a constructor for `Form1`.

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

**should be:**

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
```

Comment: im sorry. my real code is correct. just like the way u said. i made a typing error in this post. could u help me again? @Chibueze Opata

Answer (score 1):

I assume below must be the reason why your code is failing.
You have both of your forms in Form1 and Form2, where Form2 definition is done in another namespace directive, which is not integrated in the namespace of Form1, also you can't use same namespace directive name for two namespaces unless you are overriding them.

Answer (score 1):

Try this code.....

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       Form2 frm2 = new Form2();
       {
          frm2.ShowDialog();
       }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{   
  Form2.show()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

In click event of Form1 include your button:

```
string foobar = "Hello world";
Form2 frm2 = new Form2(foobar);
frm2.ShowDialog();
```

In Form2:

```
public Form2(string foobar)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    textbox1.Text = foobar;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For anybody still looking for an answer:

At the top of your code, add this namespace:

```
using YourProjectName;
```

Then, when you wish to show your form, type this:

```
var form = YourProjectName.YourFormName();
form.Show(); // Show form using new variable
```

Comment: Since for implements IDisposable, Id wrap the instantiation in a using().

using(var form = new YourFormName())
{
    form.ShowDialog();
}